# Вопрос или восклицание?

Tags: пунктуация

Писал вопрос о реях и уткнулся в еще один сложный для меня случай. А именно: предложения, первая половина которого является вопросительной, а другая - восклицательной. Предложение было такое: "Так как же все-таки правильно, подскажите, пожалуйста".
Первая часть "как правильно?" содержит вопрос, а вторая - "подскажите, пожалуйста" - призыв, восклицание. Хотя в целом предложение писалось именно ради вопроса, хотя из-за второй части, вопроса не содержащей, вопросительный знак на конце смотрится уже несколько странно. Но какой знак все-таки "победит"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из-за наличия "так как же всё-таки" вопрос не перевести в повествовательную форму. Ставьте вопросительный знак, а просьбу отделяйте (лучше первым способом).
"Так как же все-таки правильно? Подскажите, пожалуйста."
"Так как же все-таки правильно (подскажите, пожалуйста)?"